# Is it possible to plot the control chart on the matrix of Image after foreground/background approach using OTSU's approach?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, control-charts

The image is segmented using OTSU's approach in global threshold. The segmented Image is exported back into MATLAB workspace as array's with foreground/Background Values. I'm trying to plot control charts for the array. Is it possible to have such code to plot the control chart in MATLAB?

I have the value of the image segmented i.e., maskedImage data exported from the image Segmentor app in MATLAB. Expecting to plot that data array into control charts.